# Expire cookie from web server

Tags: apache-2.2, cookies

I've made some modifications on my user token and current session cookie makes server to redirect the request "in a way that will never complete".

The trick is to delog/relog, or wait for session cookie expiration. But that's not really "user friendly"....

Is there a way/command to expire existing cookie from the web server (Apache2) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in apache. The quick fix is to change the cookie name you use for the session. This will cause your application to to see them initially as new users and force everyone to login again.

Comment: This is because the cookies are managed by the CGI application, not apache.  All apache does is pass their values to the CGI application.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting cookie is setting same cookie with expiration date which is already in the past.